# How to convert string into unicode in android

Tags: android, json, unicode

I am parsing some `unicodes` from `json` to my `android` app, the api gives `unicodes` of icons like `\ue600`, When I add this unicode directly into the `textview` like `textview.setText("\ue600");` it gives right icon on the `textview`. but when i parse this unicode from `json` `api` & then I `setText` that `unicode` it just displays `\ue600` on `textview`.
How I parse or convert these strings into `unicodes` to get the icons in `textview`.

Thanks

Comment: I have already tried this but nothing works.

Comment: yes I have tried most of the unicode. They only display icon directly but not displaying the icon when parsing from json

Comment: you are getting from a rest service? if so check your db string for enabling UTF-8

Comment: in my case I will be using something like this on my db object $mysqli->set_charset("utf8") in php and mysql.

Comment: and you can try this 

new String("\ue600".getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");

Comment: I have tried this  new String("\ue600".getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
but still displays the unicode not the icon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert your `unicode` into this format `&#xe601;` & then use like this in your `textview` `textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(your_unicode_here));` 
It should work.

Comment: by your_unicode_here do you mean a hard coded unicode value or a string that is parsed from json

Comment: your_unicode_here means your string that is parsed from json.

Answer (score 2):

StringEscapeUtils does most of the work, however it only goes up to HTML4.  For characters not covered you can make your own class and add as needed.  Here is a sample class

```
public class HTMLDecoder {
    public static String decodeHTML(String html) {
        String out = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(html);
        out = out.replaceAll("Â®", "®");
        out = out.replaceAll("â\u0084¢", "™");
        return out;
    }
}
```

Add to build.bradle

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Following works fine for me.

```
String unicode = "\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F";
String Title = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(unicode);
System.out.println(Title);
```

and add dependency :  `compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'` in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: not working for \u003C

Answer (score 0):

How do you parse JSON data? If you are using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), you can use [GsonBuilder.disableHtmlEscaping()](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#disableHtmlEscaping%28%29) method in order to display proper characters instead of their code.

Answer (score 0):

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(UNICODE_CHARS));
```