# How to change color of unicode character in TextView?

Tags: android, unicode, textview

'from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode) link of wikipedia I got the code of red heart and want to show in my TextView for generating custom emoji but why is it always showing black insted of red the color of U+2665 is clearly stated red in wikipedia. below is my code

```
  TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.testText);

 //  tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("\u2665"));



tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>"+"\u2665"+"</font>"));
```

is not making it red it is still black and it shows red if i put any other text.

Comment: Font has no information about color ... They always are in the font's color color

Comment: I think you simply have to change the text color: Html.fromHtml("<font color="#FF0000">\u2665</font>")

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368856/how-to-convert-string-into-unicode-in-android/28369713#28369713

Comment: convert your unicode into Hexadecimal & use it like this. tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#x2665;"));

Comment: @Selvin please see my edit and suggest me

Comment: @theUturn this code is work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it RED you have to set it's textColor RED. Like this way ->

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.testText);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("\u2665"));
tv.setTextColor(Color.RED); // Set color here
```

Answer (score 3):

**Explanation:**
The TextView font renders this as an emoji, which means it basicly uses a predefined image, so font colors are ignored on these. There is a unicode character which can be used as a suffix, to tell the font to use the text variant (VARIATION SELECTOR 15, "\uFE0E", use like this:"\u2665\uFE0E" ), but apparently Android does ignore these, at least on my phone (Samsung SM-G800F with 5.1.1)

The stock browser and chrome also fail in recognizing the variant selector, while Firefox for Android works on my phone.

Apparently this is different accross phones, as you can see in in a [related question on Stackexchange UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/94863/samsung-android-phone-rendering-chess-unicode-as-emoji)

---

**Solution:**
What solved the problem for me, was manually setting another ttf font to the TextView, that supports these characters but not emojis, namely FreeSans from the the [GNU FreeFont Project](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/freefont/).

Download the font and put it in src/assets/fonts.
Then set the font of your TextView:

```
    Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/FreeSans.ttf");
    mTextView.setTypeface(type);
```

You should propably load the Typeface into a static constant, to avoid recreating it over and over.

Comment: That font doesn't work (defaults to Roboto) on my S8+ with 7.0. Any other fonts with no emoji?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `unicode` into `Hexadecimal` & use it like this. `tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#x2665;"));`

Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368856/how-to-convert-string-into-unicode-in-android/28369713#28369713) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Also you are set color in xml file in text view like ..

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_5"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
/>
```

and in java file to set text custom emoji its work fine.

Comment: @theUtrun its not necessary to change unicode into hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code `\u2764` for *red hearts*.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add a

> U+FE0E or in this case \uFE0E

VARIATION SELECTOR-15 after each chess piece to force them to render them as text. For reference, U+FE0F VARIATION SELECTOR-16 will force characters to render as emoji.

example :

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("\u2665\uFE0E"));
tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```